# Calling methods from a dynamic list of modules

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to do two things here, dynamically import all modules in a directory (the amount/names are unknown) and then for each of those modules found call a function called checkMe(). checkMe() is guaranteed to be in each module, so there is no need to check. This is what I have so far:

**Import**

```
import sys
import os
import glob

pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) + "/"
pathname = pathname + "/modules/"

__modules__ = [ os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in glob.glob(os.path.dirname(pathname)+"/*.py")]

for module in __modules__:
    __import__(module)
```

**Calling checkMe()**

```
for module in __modules__:
    m = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], module)
    getattr(m, 'checkMe').__call__()
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sendme'
```

(sendme is the first module)

Any help is greatly appreciated... thank you!

Comment: Add some print statement to show what you get for `pathname`, `__modules__`, etc

Comment: I'm pretty sure the imports work... I've debugged that and I get no errors for those lines anymore.

Comment: if might still be helpful to see what ends up in `__module__`. I'd pretty much add print statements any time you assign to a variable so you can track state throughout the application and figure out where things go wrong.

Comment: @rafe Ahhhh, I see what you're saying. I do actually have those print statements, I've just edited them out to post onto here. They print out what I'd expect, though I can't 100% confirm that the imports are working due to my difficulty calling the methods in those modules

Answer (score 0):

`__import__` has some tricky semantics regarding packages (directories containing an `__init__.py`) vs modules. You would need to use the `fromlist` argument to make it work. As it is, running a module by path is easiest with `runpy` (from the comments: run_path needs Python 2.7 or newer):

```
import runpy
runpy.run_path('path/to/file.py')
```

Comment: Like I said above, I'm pretty sure the import is working, it's the calling of methods in those modules that I'm having the real trouble with

Comment: @pdeuchler No, import is not returning the module you expect. `help(__import__)` should convince you.

Comment: @Tobu: "When importing a module from a package, note that `__import__('A.B', ...)` returns package A when fromlist is empty, but its submodule B when fromlist is not empty." That?

Comment: @JAB yes. Btw, `__import__` uses `sys.path`, which is another reason `runpy.run_path` is more suitable here.

Comment: Since pdeuchler knows what the starting path is, though, he could always put `sys.path.append(pathname)` in there somewhere. Also, I was going to ask what happens if the module contains code that's executed when run as a script, but then I noticed the part where it says "`__name__` is set to `run_name` if this optional argument is not `None` and to `'<run_path>'` otherwise." So `__name__ == '__main__'` conditionals wouldn't be triggered. Oh, and you should probably have mentioned that `runpy` only has a `run_path` method in Pythons 2.7.x and 3.2+. That tripped me up until I double-checked.

Comment: @JAB @Tobu The compatibility isn't an issue, and thank you. Will changing this also enable me to run functions within these modules easier?